# wayland and remote desktop

Tags: remote-access, wayland

apparently Fedora 25, even if in alpha state (not for long, beta comins soon) is doing extremely well with Wayland enable by defaut. I wonder if there's any graphical/easy_to_setup solution out there for remote desktop management (under another linux machine) out there that will work with Wayland? Or is it too early? Any help appreciated, thanks

Comment: I've voted to close this since it is clearly off-topic. Note for others: this was cross-posted _from_ [unix.se] for some reason: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/314946/12606. That is a much better place for it, so closing and deleting here causes very little harm.

Answer (score 0):

It isn’t supported yet. The official answer is “use X if you need remote desktop access.”

Answer (score -1):

Open terminal - type "sudo nano /etc/gdm/custom.conf
"
UnComment - Wayaland=false
Uncomment - Enable=true

Restart your system - Now you can use Anydesk
Works good even on fedora 38